# How do I pass a include path to windres?

Tags: linux, mingw

I am trying to cross compile libiconv-1.13.1 for windows using mingw32.
I have got a custom toolchain placed in /usr/i686-w64-mingw32/bin/
This is for the NetSurf browser project.
I have set the paths to use this toolchain before calling configure:

```
sudo CC="/usr/i686-w64-mingw32/bin/i686-w64-mingw32-gcc -B/usr/i686-w64-mingw32/bin/i686-w64-mingw32-ld" AR="/usr/i686-w64-mingw32/bin/i686-w64-mingw32-gcc-ar" RANLIB="/usr/i686-w64-mingw32/bin/i686-w64-mingw32-gcc-ranlib" CFLAGS="-I/usr/i686-w64-mingw32/i686-w64-mingw32/include -DNO_FSEEKO" LDFLAGS="-L/usr/i686-w64-mingw32/i686-w64-mingw32/lib" ./configure --prefix=/usr/i686-w64-mingw32/ --host=i686-w64-mingw32 --disable-shared
```

So the configure finished and compilation started. The include path is shown in the compile commands so its set correctly. There is a step involving windres:

```
/bin/bash ../libtool --mode=compile --tag=RC i686-w64-mingw32-windres `/bin/sh ./../windows/windres-options --escape 1.13.1` -i ./../windows/libiconv.rc -o libiconv.res.lo --output-format=coff
libtool: compile:  i686-w64-mingw32-windres -DPACKAGE_VERSION_STRING=\\\"1.13.1\\\" -DPACKAGE_VERSION_MAJOR=1 -DPACKAGE_VERSION_MINOR=13 -DPACKAGE_VERSION_SUBMINOR=1 -i ./../windows/libiconv.rc --output-format=coff -o libiconv.res.o
./../windows/libiconv.rc:3:10: fatal error: winver.h: No such file or directory
    3 | #include <winver.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
i686-w64-mingw32-windres: preprocessing failed.
make[1]: *** [Makefile:93: libiconv.res.lo] Error 1
```

It seems that the include path was not passed when i686-w64-mingw32-windres was invoked on windows/libiconv.rc
The include path '/usr/i686-w64-mingw32/i686-w64-mingw32/include' does have the file winver.h

I am not familiar with how to pass an include path to this tool. There is a windres option file beside the .rc file:  https://git.savannah.gnu.org/gitweb/?p=libiconv.git;a=blob;f=windows/windres-options;h=779fddec305d1e78f1e5c3123683b3c380e4a82e;hb=HEAD

Maybe I need to change something in the configure script: https://git.savannah.gnu.org/gitweb/?p=libiconv.git;a=tree;hb=HEAD

So any help with this error would be really helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Brief warning into this:I am a Windows user, and I don't mess with ./configure or makefiles. That said, I have figured out how to manually compile this, so here's my words on it.

The way I circumvented this issue in my own automation attempts is to call WindRes directly, and use the `-I <directory>` flag. GCC doesn't appear to play nice with trying to pass the include flag over to WindRes for whatever reason. Please note that you CANNOT use quotation locking on this, as I've painfully found out. I'm not sure that's as big of a deal on Linux based OSes though.

To manually compile it, the chain is compile the .c files as objects->run WindRes separately->linking them together. That looks a bit like below on Windows.

```
C:\Users\Workspace\Desktop\Compilers\mingw64\bin>gcc.exe "C:\Users\Workspace\Desktop\Sources\Win32 Experiment\src\main.c" -iquote"C:/Users/Workspace/Desktop/Sources/Win32 Experiment/includes" -c -Wall -o"C:\Users\Workspace\Desktop\Compiled\Win32 Experiment\Code.o"
C:\Users\Workspace\Desktop\Compilers\mingw64\bin>windres.exe -I C:\Users\WORKSP~1\Desktop\Sources\WIN32E~1/includes/ -v "C:\Users\Workspace\Desktop\Sources\Win32 Experiment\res\main.rc" "C:\Users\Workspace\Desktop\Compiled\Win32 Experiment\Resource.o"
C:\Users\Workspace\Desktop\Compilers\mingw64\bin>gcc.exe "C:\Users\Workspace\Desktop\Compiled\Win32 Experiment\Code.o" "C:\Users\Workspace\Desktop\Compiled\Win32 Experiment\Resource.o" -o "C:\Users\Workspace\Desktop\Compiled\Win32 Experiment\Build.exe" -ggdb -lcomctl32 -Wl,--subsystem,windows
```

Unfortunately, I haven't quite figured out an intelligent way to manually compile all of the .c files as separate objects, which is what makefiles like to do. I suppose, if it's possible, you could simply modify the configuration to just process the .cxx and .c files, and then link it together.

Thankfully, GCC accepts wildcards for multiple files in the linking stage, so you don't need to define them separately like I did.